# Generics Java, unbounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, unbounded-wildcard

Hi directly from a java tutorial provided by Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

```
static void filter(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Iterator<?> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (!cond(it.next()))
            it.remove();
}
```

I am aware of the type erasure at compilation time. And I am aware also of that a type  (unbounded) is going to be substituted with Object. Being aware of that what is going to do the compiler with the unbounded wild card  at compilation time? Just removing it as it was a raw type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OP, Type erasure happens at run-time not at compile time, correct it in your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a generic declaration

```
interface Foo<T>
    T get();
    void set(T);
    void bet();
```

A raw type `Foo` is equivalent to a type declared as

```
interface Foo
    Object get();
    void set(Object);
    void bet();
    // all generics info are stripped
```

For example, in Java 5 we have `List<E>`, its raw version `List` contains the exact same method signatures as the pre-java5 `List` interface. Raw type is used for backward compatibility.

Raw `List` is pretty close to `List<Object>`; but very different from `List<?>`

---

An object `foo` of type `Foo<?>` has the type of

```
interface Foo<X>
    X get();
    void set(X);
    void bet();
```

for some definitive, albeit unknown, type X. Though X is unknown, we can still invoke `foo.get()` and `foo.bet()`. But we can't invoke `foo.set(a)` because there's no way to know whether `a` is of the unknown type `X` - unless `a` is `null`.

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered before: [Java Generics - What's really in a unbounded wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796220/java-generics-whats-really-in-a-unbounded-wildcard?rq=1) and [Difference between an unbound wildcard and a raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242174/difference-between-an-unbound-wildcard-and-a-raw-type?rq=1) for example.

So, yes, `<?>` and raw types are identical (at run time).

Comment: No, they are not identical(at least at compile time). They are quite the opposite, you can add anything into a Raw type but cannot add anyting(except null) into unbounded wilcards list.But i am not sure if they are identical or not during run time tough

Comment: They are identical during runtime, see first link. Why did you delete your first answer if you still defend it now?

Comment: my first part was right. as it was regarding compiler time, but my last part during run time was total bogus. :P, that was the reason i deleted my answer. however, you should mention that in your answer regarding run time . :)

Comment: At runtime all `List<whatever>` and `List` are identical, but that has nothing to do with the unbounded wildcard specifically, thus isn't an explanation.

Comment: hmm just checked the byte code generated for both `List<?>` and List. they are absolutely identical. but not sure we can consider them identical thou. but as far as i underdtand from marko's comments in my deleted answer.We shouldn't really talk about generics at run time . :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks marko. it does make sense now. I just checked the byte code for raw type, parameterized type and unbounded type list. all produced same byte code. :)

Comment: @PermGenError If you have an upper-bounded parameter, that will produce downcasts in the bytecode (for example, on the result of `get`). Whether we count that as "different types at runtime" is debatable, but the fact stays that the runtime type of the instance in question is still exactly the same.