# Cannot add an object to List<?> instantiated as ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, generics

I ask this question because of [a discussion about one answer here on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49777057/5899172). The statement is the following:

Given the following code:

```
List<?> list =new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Why can't we do:

```
Integer e = 2;
list.add(e);
```

This throws a compiler error, despite the fact that we instantiated the list as an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Why is that ?

Comment: because you explicitly have taken information away from the compiler, the compiler does not know the *actual* type of the instance at runtime, it knows only the type you write down: `List<?>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a `List<?>` could be any sort of List (`List<String>` for example). And the compiler should not permit adding the wrong type to a list.

However, if you know the actual class then you can do a class cast at runtime:

```
((List<Integer>)list).add(e);
```

Code like this should be avoided since it can generate a ClassCastException if an unexpected type is encountered at runtime. To make matters worse (as noted by [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302)), our ClassCastException might only occur in an entirely different area of the code-- namely, when we are retrieving something from the list.

**A better approach**

If you know that the list will be of a specific type or a superclass of that type, then you could define the variable using a bounded wildcard:

```
List<? super Integer> list;
Integer e = 2;

list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(e);

list = new ArrayList<Number>();
list.add(e);

list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(e);
```

This approach, as noted by [M. Prokhorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7470253/m-prokhorov), allows us to avoid the need for an inadvisable cast.

Comment: Note that the code shown will **not** produce a `ClassCastException`, not even for `List<String>` - it will run just fine, only when retrieving something from the list a `ClassCastException` might occur.

Comment: Should also note that compiler will permit adding elements to a list which is defined as `? super T`, where it would allow adding elements of `T` or any superclass thereof (except when `T` is interface, you can't add `Object` to the mix, that one won't work).

Comment: I would make the casting approach the last part of the answer, rather than the first part.  No one should *ever* be doing an unsafe cast like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an Arraylist of  and they will let you add all, because Integer, String and Boolean are child or in other words Object class is their parent.

Comment: It does not the "why" question, tho. The question is not here to find a workaround (I already have one), it is to provide information on *why* this behavior happens. Remember it when it comes to answering questions.